# gedit - show file path for recently opened files

Tags: files, gedit

`Gedit` shows the recently opened files.

How do I make `gedit` show not only the file-names but also the file path for recently opened files?

I work on a website which has an `index.tcl / index.adb` in many locations. So I have for example 3 time `index.tcl`. But I'd like to know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be of course to edit the code of `gedit`. Since that seems out of reach, the solution below is a workaround.

---

If the path information of recently used gedit files is important to you, the soluution can be used as a replacement of gedit's own "recently used" overview. It gives you the information, exactly as it appears on your `gedit` window's title bar, of the last ten used files .

[image]

It exist of:

1. a (very light) background script, keeping track of possibly opened `gedit` files
2. a script to call a list of the most recently used files.

Simply run script `[1]` in the background, put script `[2]` under a shortcut key or add it as a shortcut to the `gedit` launcher's quicklist.

The result:

#### How to setup

The setup needs `wmctrl` to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get wmctrl
```

Then:

1. Copy the script below (`[1]`) into an empty file, save it as `get_latestgedit.py`

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import os
   import time
   import socket

   f = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.latest_gedit.txt"
   n = 10

   def get():
       try:
           pid = subprocess.check_output(["pidof", "gedit"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
           gedit_w =subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8")
           matches = [l.split(socket.gethostname())[1] for l in gedit_w.splitlines() if all(
               [pid in l, "~" in l or "/" in l])]
           return matches
       except:
           return []

   gedit_windows1 = get()
   try:
       latest = open(f).read().splitlines()
   except FileNotFoundError:
       latest = []

   while True:
       time.sleep(5)
       gedit_windows2 = get()
       new = [w for w in gedit_windows2 if not w in gedit_windows1]
       if len(new) != 0:
           for w in [w for w in gedit_windows2 if not w in gedit_windows1]:
               try:
                   latest.remove(w)
               except ValueError:
                   pass
               latest.append(w)
           if len(latest) > n:
               latest = latest[(len(latest) - n):]
           with open(f, "wt") as out:
               for item in latest:
                   out.write(item+"\n")
       gedit_windows1 = gedit_windows2
   ```
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `get_geditlist.py`:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import os
   import sys

   f = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.latest_gedit.txt"

   try:
       ws = open(f).read().splitlines()[::-1]
   except FileNotFoundError:
       open(f, "wt").write("")

   try:
       cmd = 'zenity --list --title="Choose"'+ \
                     ' --text ""'+ \
                     ' --column="Latest opened" '+\
                     (" ").join(['"'+s.strip()+'"' for s in ws])
       to_open = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8").split("|")[0]
       path = to_open[to_open.find("(")+1: to_open.find(")")].strip()+"/"+to_open[:to_open.find("(")].strip()
       sections = [s for s in (path.split("/"))]
       for i, it in enumerate(sections):
           if it.count(" ") != 0:
               sections[i] = '"'+it+'"'
       path = ("/").join(sections)
       command = "gedit "+path
       subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
   except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
       pass
   ```
3. Open a terminal window, test-drive script `[1]` with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/get_latestgedit.py
   ```

   While the script runs, open a few existing `gedit` files, leave them open for at least 5-10 seconds (the loop break time). Now test-run script `[2]` with the command (from another terminal) with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/get_geditlist.py
   ```

   The most recent `gedit` files should show up, as shown in the image.
4. If all works fine, add script `[1]` to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/get_latestgedit.py
   ```

   and add script `[2]` to a shortcut key: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10&&python3 /path/to/get_geditlist.py"
   ```

   ***Or***,

   add it as a quicklist item to your `gedit` launcher, as shown in the image:

   [image]

   - Copy the `gedit` launcher from `/usr/share/applications to`~/.local/share/applications`:

     ```
     cp /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
     ```
   - Open the local copy in `gedit`:

     ```
     gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gedit.desktop
     ```
   - Look for the line:

     ```
     Actions=Window;Document;
     ```

   change it to:

   ```
       Actions=Window;Document;Recently used;
   ```

   - To the very end, add a section to the file:

     ```
     [Desktop Action Recently used]
     Name=Recently used
     Exec=python3 /path/to/get_geditlist.py
     OnlyShowIn=Unity;
     ```

   Of course, replace `python3 /path/to/get_geditlist.py` by the real path to the script `[2]`

#### Explanation

**Script `[1]`** checks (once per five seconds):

- if `gedit` windows are opened, by checking if the `pidof gedit` has a valid output. Then, if so:
- it checks if `gedit`'s pid occurs in one or more lines in the output of `wmctrl -lp`. If so, it filters out the lines, *not* containing a valid path between "(" and ")", since those windows are not from *saved* files.
- The remaining windows are added to a list of recently used windows. If the window (the file) already occurs in the list, its chronological position is updated. Furthermore, the script deletes all (oldest) windows when the list exceeds a length of ten (windows).

If the list of recently used windows changes, the list is written to a hidden file in your `home` directory.

**Script `[2]`** reads the hidden file, created and updated by scrip1 `[1]`. When called:

- the script reads the lines in the hidden file, containing the window's titles.
- from the titles, the *path* is parsed out, and the window titles appear in a `Zenity` list.
- If the user choosen a window from the list, the path to the file is "fixed" for possibly occurring spaces in either the path or the filename, subsequently the file is opened with `gedit`.

Comment: @Jacom Vlijm thx for the repy. The test does not succeed - since I'm not used to python I'll have to debug it in the next days (not much time to do debugging / lerning python

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues Hi Thorsten, there should be nothing to debug, but if you post back what is the terminal output, we'll have it fixed no doubt. That is if you like the solution. Does script `[1]` run, and does it create a file `~/.latest_gedit.txt` if you open `gedit` files for at least a few seconds??

Comment: @Jacom Vlijm the problem was that 'wmctrl' was not installed. Not the script works - thanks.

Comment: Hi @ThorstenNiehues Thanks for the edit, but I'd prefer not importing additional stuff if it does not add functionality :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack, just open all files you think you want, then at the top right menu you can find the path of each file, so you can keep what you want and close others.

[image]

Comment: OK that's what I am doing now - but it's annoying

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues I don't think there is other way in native gedit

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance, someone's still wondering, **[gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit)** has natively implemented  showing path of a file in multiple ways. It must've been available for a long time now but v3.36.2 has it for sure.