# Help with syntax and customization of .desktop files for Unity

Tags: unity, firefox, customization, .desktop, launcher

1. I tried below, and it works as expected. Sandboxing Firefox in a volatile state through **Firejail**.

   ```
   Exec=firejail --seccomp --private firefox
   ```
2. What is this for? And what does it do?

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;
   ```
3. My `Firefox.desktop` code so far

   ```
   [Desktop Entry] Version=1.0
   Name=VOLATILE SANDBOX - Private Firefox 
   Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
   GenericName=Web Browser
   Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
   Exec=firejail --seccomp --private firefox
   Terminal=false
   X-MultipleArgs=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=firefox
   Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
   MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
   StartupNotify=true
   Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;
   ```
4. I want to add right-click states: **Persistent** and **unsafe**, so you can upgrade extensions. How would I add a second and third state (in my code)?

   ```
   Exec=firejail firefox
   ```

   and

   ```
   Exec=firefox
   ```

Comment: please keep to one question per post - otherwise it may be impossible for one person to give a good answer.

Comment: Posted my answer. Please let me know if all is clear.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks, it cleared up my confusion. I was able to make a working .desktop file. I will be back with more questions :)

Comment: @Ubuntu_Chef perfect, looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limiting/changing your question a bit into "What are the different sections in a `.desktop` file for?"

### Explanation of different sections in a .desktop file

In my answer, I will use a simple `.desktop`file, since the example of `firefox` has *many* distracting lines, not making the answer any clearer.

The principle however is exactly the same for all `.desktop` files, to be used in `Unity`.

#### 1. The "body" of a basic `.desktop` file

Say you have an application (`gedit` in the example), but no `.desktop` file. You could simply create a file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gedit
Exec=gedit
Type=Application
```

name it e.g. `gedit_starter.desktop`. To use it from your desktop (double-click to run the command `gedit`), simply make it executable. To make it appear in Dash, save it in either `/usr/share/applications` (for global use) or `~/.local/share/applications` (for local, personal use).

#### Adding extra options (entry keys)

The example above is a `.desktop` file in its simplest form; a simple command, a generic icon. You can add additional lines, to give the `.desktop` file an icon, add extra options or localized names etc. See [this link](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) to find options to add entry keys, such as a customized icon.

Note that the (possibly set-) icon and the set name (in the `Name=` line) will *not* show on the file if you store it on your desktop, *unless* you make it executable. See below the example of firefox:

*non-executable*

[image]

*executable*

[image]

#### 2. Adding right-click items (from the Unity Launcher)

[image]

The section, as mentioned in `[1.]` contains the "main" command of the launcher file. This will run if you click on it (`Unity`). To create right-click items, you need two additional sections:

- a line, listing those additional right-click options, separated by a `";"`. 
  From the "real" ``` gedit``.desktop ``` file's example:

  ```
  Actions=Window;Document;
  ```

  Each of these items corresponds to:
- a shortcut section, like:

  ```
  [Desktop Action Window]
  Name=Open a New Window
  Exec=gedit --new-window
  OnlyShowIn=Unity;
  ```

  Looking into this section:

  ```
  [Desktop Action Window]
  ```

  refers to the name, as listed in the `Actions=` line. The name may contain spaces, e.g.`Recently used`, as I did in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/643543/72216).

  ```
  Name=Open a New Window
  ```

  refers to the name, as it appears in your interface

  ```
  Exec=gedit --new-window
  ```

  refers to the command to run on right-click

  ```
  OnlyShowIn=Unity;
  ```

  refers to the desktop environments that should display the desktop entry

That is basically how it works.

#### Your example

If I understand your question well, and you want to add both *Persistent* and *unsafe* to your firefox quicklist (as a right-click option), you'd need to change the line:

```
Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;
```

into:

```
Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;Persistant;unsafe;
```

and add to the bottom of the file two shortcut sections:

```
    [Desktop Action Persistant]
    Name=Persistant
    Exec=<command>
    OnlyShowIn=Unity;


    [Desktop Action unsafe]
    Name=unsafe
    Exec=<command>
    OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

where you need to replace both `<command>` by the commands you want it to run.

#### Note

If you want to edit a `.desktop`file, always copy the default (global) file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` (for local, personal use), and edit the local one. After log out / in, the local one will overrule the global one.

Answer (score 0):

By the way if you do this and then have trouble actually opening links in Firefox (or any program) as a "default app" for a filetype, try adding %U to the Exec line, like this:

```
Exec=firefox %U
```

The %U is a placeholder for the URL being passed to the program. I think other placeholders are available as well, this is just what worked for me in Firefox.